# What is the correct way to deploy from ADO to an on premise Azure Service Fabric Cluster using gMSA?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory

I have looked for documentation on the right set of steps to get an agent within our network to deploy to a service fabric cluster (also within our network) using gMSA.

The error received is "##[error]Could not ping any of the provided Service Fabric gateway endpoints."

The same agent can connect to the cluster using PowerShell just fine. What's worse, there is a development cluster on the agent itself and it cannot even connect to that.

There is nothing about how to ensure an on-prem agent can connect to an on-prem machine if using the online version (Azure DevOps) and gMSA for the Service Connection. If anyone has had success in this area or has pointers to better documentation, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'd think your agent service needs to run under the gMSA identity, not under system identity or network service. reinstall it\reconfigure it to use gMSA identity and it should work

Comment: I was able to get the agent service running on what we will call BUILD01 under the gMSA. That gMSA has admin rights to the cluster. From BUILD01 I can connect to the cluster I'm targeting with Connect-ServiceFabricCluster. It's only when BUILD01 tries to utilize the Deploy Service Fabric Application Step that I get the error:

"System.Fabric.FabricTransientException: Could not ping any of the provided Service Fabric gateway endpoints. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Exception from HRESULT: 0x80071C49"

Comment: did you test connecting to the cluster using gMSA or not? because from what you are saying it seems like you are using your own identity to connect from the agent machine, which is not the equivalent of connecting with gMSA. also, running agent under gMSA might not be supported at all.